# DataGrid ItemRenderer Error

Tags: xml, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4

I am populating 3 columns of my datagrid using a simple XML file. The last column is supposed to be an itemrenderer, basically a Button. However the button should appear only on certain rows of the 3rd column of the datagrid depending on the value from the XML file, which is either "true" or "false". So basically I want to set the Visible property of the button in the itemrenderer to true or false.

```
    Here is the whole application

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" pageTitle="Dynamic Data Grid">
        <!--    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"/>
        </s:layout>-->

        <fx:Declarations>
            <s:ArrayList id="cccb_dp">
                <fx:String>User1</fx:String>
                <fx:String>User2</fx:String>
                <fx:String>User3</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayList>

            <fx:XML id="tempXML" source="assets/fieldsXML.xml"/>
            <s:XMLListCollection id="fieldsXMLList" source="{tempXML.worker}"/>

        </fx:Declarations>

        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout/>
        </s:layout>

        <s:VGroup verticalAlign="middle" horizontalCenter="1" verticalCenter="1" horizontalAlign="center">

            <s:HGroup horizontalAlign="center" verticalCenter="-221" width="580" height="158" x="75">
                <s:Label text="CC" width="23" height="24" verticalAlign="middle" fontWeight="bold"/>
                <s:DropDownList id="cc_cb" dataProvider="{cccb_dp}" width="175"/>
            </s:HGroup>

            <mx:DataGrid id="myDG" dataProvider="{fieldsXMLList}">
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Header1" dataField="@field_label"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Header2" dataField="@field_value"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Header3">
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <fx:Component>
                                <s:Button click="onClick(event)" label="Click Me" dataChange="onDataChange(event)" >
                                    <fx:Script>
                                        <![CDATA[
                                            import mx.controls.Alert;

                                            private function onClick(evt:Event):void
                                            {
                                                Alert.show(data.@field_visibility);
                                            }
                                            private function onDataChange(evt:Event):void
                                            {
                                                visible=data.@field_visibility;
                                            }
                                        ]]>
                                    </fx:Script>
                                </s:Button>
                            </fx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                    </mx:DataGridColumn>
                </mx:columns>
            </mx:DataGrid>

        </s:VGroup>

    </s:Application>


    The XML:
    <worker_fields>
        <worker id="1" field_label="Seller" field_value="5" field_visibility="false"/>
        <worker id="1" field_label="Balance" field_value="100" field_visibility="true"/>
        <worker id="1" field_label="Cash Owned" field_value="300" field_visibility="true"/>

        <worker id="2" field_label="Seller" field_value="5" field_visibility="false"/>
        <worker id="2" field_label="Balance" field_value="130" field_visibility="true"/>
        <worker id="2" field_label="Cash Owned" field_value="132" field_visibility="false"/>
        <worker id="2" field_label="Credits" field_value="131" field_visibility="true"/>
    </worker_fields>    


Any idea how to go around it.  

Thanks you for the precious help.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each itemRenderer gets a data object; which contains the element the renderer is displaying.  There is not going to be a property named field_visibility in your renderer because it is not a default property and you didn't create one.

However, it should be a property on the data object passed into the renderer.

The data property should point to a single worker:

```
<worker id="1" field_label="Cash Owned" field_value="300" field_visibility="true"/>
```

And you should be able to access it with slight mods to your code:

```
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <mx:Button click="onClick(event)" label="Click Me" visible="{data.@field_visibility}">
                    <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import mx.controls.Alert;

                        private function onClick(evt:Event):void
                        {
                            Alert.show(data.field_visibility);
                        }
                    ]]>
                    </fx:Script>
                </mx:Button>
            </fx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
```

For best results; you should consider listening to the data change event and changing the visibility in that way.  This is known to cause less issues, long term, than the use of binding:

```
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <mx:Button click="onClick(event)" label="Click Me" dataChange="onDataChange()" >
                    <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import mx.controls.Alert;

                        private function onClick(evt:Event):void
                        {
                            Alert.show(data.field_visibility);
                        }
                        private function onDataChange(evt:Event):void
                        {
                            visible=data.@field_visibility";
                        }
                    ]]>
                    </fx:Script>
                </mx:Button>
            </fx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
```

---

For some reason the original posters last code edit wiped out his actual question.  Flex is having an issue translating the the XML string value into a Boolean value.  `data.@field_visibility` appears to be returning an XMLList.  As a Boolean value that will always be true. That is issue one.  It can be solved by doing a conditional like this:

```
if(data.@field_visibility == "true"){
 this.button.visible = true;
} else {
 this.button.visible = false;
}
```

The second issue is that the button doesn't appear to vanish if it is the top level component.  So, you need to place it inside a container.  I used a Canvas.

Here is modified application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" pageTitle="Dynamic Data Grid">
    <!--    <s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"/>
    </s:layout>-->

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:ArrayList id="cccb_dp">
            <fx:String>User1</fx:String>
            <fx:String>User2</fx:String>
            <fx:String>User3</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayList>

        <fx:XML id="tempXML" source="assets/fieldsXML.xml"/>
        <s:XMLListCollection id="fieldsXMLList" source="{tempXML.worker}"/>

    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:VGroup verticalAlign="middle" horizontalCenter="1" verticalCenter="1" horizontalAlign="center">

        <s:Button click="{myDG.invalidateList()}" label="Invalidate List" />
        <s:HGroup horizontalAlign="center" verticalCenter="-221" width="580" height="158" x="75">
            <s:Label text="CC" width="23" height="24" verticalAlign="middle" fontWeight="bold"/>
            <s:DropDownList id="cc_cb" dataProvider="{cccb_dp}" width="175"/>
        </s:HGroup>

        <mx:DataGrid id="myDG" dataProvider="{fieldsXMLList}">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Header1" dataField="@field_label"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Header2" dataField="@field_value"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Header3">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <mx:Canvas dataChange="container1_dataChangeHandler(event)" >
                                <mx:Button label="Click Me" id="button"  />
                                <fx:Script>
                                    <![CDATA[
                                        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                                        protected function container1_dataChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                                        {
                                            if(data.@field_visibility == "true"){
                                                this.button.visible = true;
                                            } else {
                                                this.button.visible = false;
                                            }
                                        }

                                    ]]>
                                </fx:Script>
                            </mx:Canvas>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:DataGridColumn>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>

    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Binding will fail with an XMLList. All buttons will be visible if you don't use the 'dataChange' approach.

Comment: using data.@field_visibility removes the error but it still does not work. I did the exact same as your second suggestion. The button is being displayed on every row of column3 irrespective of the value of field_visibility 'true' or 'false'

Any idea?

Comment: @RIAStar thanks for the clarification; I don't deal with XML that much.

Comment: @FlexyBoz give us a full runnable sample that I can copy and paste into a Flex app and I can try it.

Comment: @ www.Flextras.com

I edited the original question and posted a sample application. Grateful if youc an have a look. Thanks

Comment: @FlexyBoz That's because the value of an XML attibute (in this case `data.@field_visibility`) is always a String. Both `"true"` and `"false"` evaluate to `true`. Replace it with this: `visible = data.@field_visibility == "true"`, which tests the String value.

Comment: @FlexyBoz I updated my answer w/ a solution.  You switched from using an MX button in your original code to a Spark button in the updated sample.  Your updated sample wouldn't compile b/c a Spark button must be wrapped in another component, I believe an MXItemRenderer.  I just switched back to using an MX Button for simplicity.  The issue is that your XML value is returning an XMLList object; which is treated as "True" in the Boolean sense.  Also the button needs to be wrapped in a container for it to disappear.

Comment: Also; your code edit to the original questin wiped out all of your question content, except for the actual code.  You should fix that.

Comment: I really appreciate the constructive explanation that you all have been giving to reach to this answer.

Just a recap for those who come are interested in this issue:

1) It is imperative to use the dataChange method in this solution
2)XML attributes are of type String here, thus evaluation of data.@field_visibility resolves to True always.
3) Button needs to be wrapped in a container so that the do not show since they are top level components.

@www.Flextras.com I rectified the original post, now its complete.

Thanks for the workings.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @www.Flextras.com's answer.

If you want to rely on your column's `dataField` property and make your renderer data agnostic, you can implement [`mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/IDropInListItemRenderer.html) interface in your renderer. As far as you inherited from MX `Button` which already implemented it the code will be the following:

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{fieldsXMLList}" id="myDG">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="@field_label" headerText="Header1" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="@field_value" headerText="Header2" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="@field_visibility" headerText="Header3">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:Button click="onClick(event)" label="Click Me" visible="{data[listData.dataField]}">
                        <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            import mx.controls.Alert;

                            private function onClick(evt:Event):void
                            {
                                Alert.show(data[listData.dataField]);
                            }
                        ]]>
                        </fx:Script>
                    </mx:Button>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: The MX Button already implements IDropInListItemRenderer http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Button.html

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Thank you for pointing that. I wrote this snippet right in web form so forget about it :)

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I've modified the answer with your suggestion.